# How to finish an Activity (Before calling an new one)

Tags: android

I know about `finish()` method but is there a way to finish an activity completely before calling a new activity?

if you do

```
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

You are starting a new activity before closing the previous activity completely.

Is there a way to close an activity completely before calling a new one?

Thanks a lot in advance.

EDIT: I need this because the old activity is a drawing file. The new activity is a listView activity. When a user close drawing file and start listView, that drawing file doesn't show up in listView. When I update listView using onClickListener of a button afterwards, listView gets updated - I think this is because the previous activity which was using the file is closed completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put 
Intent intent = new Intent(iContext, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);

at the end of the onDestroy. The listView now gets updated when the new activity shows up. Thanks for the help guys tho!

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

Add `nohistory` in Your `manifest.xml`.

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

else,

```
Intent I = new Intent(A.this, B.class);
startActivity(I);
 A.this.finish();
```

This A activity will be close

Comment: I was using this before Intent intent = new Intent(iContext, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish(); And I think yours does the same job - it opens the activity B and then closes Activity A. Is there a way to close activity A first and then open activity B?

Comment: change ur manifest.xml first activity is b and next activity a. You will get solution

Answer (score 2):

Use this.finish(). or

use android:nohistory="true" in Android Manifest for an activity.

Even you can use System.exit(0).It will close the previous activity.

Comment: Is there a way to close the previous activity completely before starting a new one?

Comment: @coolcool1994 why do you want to do that, please state in question.

Comment: The file doesn't close completely and listview (new activity) doesn't include the file which the previous activity was manipulating. . . I ll add that

Comment: android:noHistory="true"
--> "H", not "h"